# Updating UITableViewDelegate not on draw

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a class definition as follows:

```
@interface ClassViewController : ContentViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView* mTableView;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView* mTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* feeds;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData* responseData;
```

I'm trying to load contents after a JSON request. However, the table doesn't update with the new contents until after I manipulate the screen (e.g., scroll down).

I am using `[self->mTableView reloadData];` to no effect. Also, in:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I'm setting:

```
self.mTableView = tableView;
```

Otherwise the results don't propagate to the table at all.

Is there something I'm missing, or should that `self.mTableView` definition be placed elsewhere?

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS development, so if I'm leaving something out, please let me know.

Comment: You can define self.mTableView in IB. Declaring it as an IBOutlet allows you to control drag from your view controller to the table view to do this. Calling reloadData once your data source has been updated should be all you need for the data to display. I don't know whether hooking up your outlet will fix your issue, though.

Comment: Like so? `IBOutlet UITableView* mTableView;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

(1) Connect `mTableView` to the table view object in Interface Builder.

(2) Note that you can just use property notation `self.mTableView` rather than `self->mTableView`.

(1) will fix your problem.  (2) is just a style issue (mainly).

[image]

Comment: `mTableView` is not listed as an outlet. I define it as such: `IBOutlet UITableView* mTableView;`. Is that incorrect? Thanks by the way